# How to pull specific content from Webpage into Email using AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

The Webpage I am talking about is a Blog 'http://www.example.com/blog/'. When an email is send I want to get the Title of the latest Blog published on this Blog page and include it in my email.

I am looking for any suggestion OR even an answer on whether it is possible or not.

So if this the HTML in the Blog page :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h2 class="post-item__title">
     <a href="http://www.example.com/blog/latest-blog">TITLE THAT I NEED TO PULL INTO THE EMAIL</a>
  </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted, so others can see this has been resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `HTTPGet(1,2,3,4)`-AMPscript function and then parse your html-code (for example using `IndexOf(@VarNameOfHTTPGetResponse, "the_content")` and `Substring(1,2,3)`. But it would be easier to use in AMPscript if you add an API-route to your blog-server which just returns the title.

Further information on the usage of the functions can be found here:

- [IndexOf(1,2) - Marketing Cloud Documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/indexof/)
- [Substring(1,2,3) - Marketing Cloud Documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/substring/)
- [HTTPGet(1,2,3,4) - Marketing Cloud Documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/httpget/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Markus. I will check if I am able to implement your suggestion and get back